# Windows 10 Pro, version 1709 Build 16299.125 - miktex

Tags: miktex

After downloading the version - basic-miktex-2.9.6615 for a new laptop i cannot install.
The error message appear immediately when running the setup file : 
"
The operation could not be completed for the following reason:

A required file system path could not be retrieved.

Details: nfolder="38", hr="-2147024891"
"

Hope you can help to solve that,
Thanks and Regards,
Romi

Answer (score 1):

McAfee Endpoint Security blocked the program from running.
After removed temporary the antivirus- it fixed.

Comment: Good. Now, in general, I advise users to try the "portable" version of MikTeX instead of the regular installer. Avoids many installation problems, and does not require admin privilege or disabling antivirus.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, so I create folder: MiKTeX Download Files in C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop 
and follow the help on youtube: 
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Tutorial-+Installing+LaTeX-MiKTeX+and+Texmaker+on+a+Windows+10+System+%28Version+2019

Thanks Dr. Manuel Kuehner (Germany)